# Is there a userspace equivalent to the Linux kernel's alternative() macro?

Tags: linux, performance, x86, instrumentation

The Linux kernel has an `alternative()` [macro](https://lwn.net/Articles/164121/) which allows the developer to specify multiple implementations for a sequence of code, with the particular alternative to use selected at runtime (*early in the boot process* in the case of the kernel `alternative()` macro).

Is there a reasonable way to achieve something similar for a user-mode application? In particular, the recording of the alternative locations and the runtime patching code.

It could be useful for semi-static instrumentation: instrumentation that can be enable or disabled at runtime, but still "compiled-in" only to specific locations.

Comment: Look up "GNU IFUNC"

Comment: I don't see the difference of what you are asking to a simple `if` statement. Read an environment variable or a command line flag, and `if` on it?

Comment: @Aganju: functionally, there is no difference. It's only for performance.

Comment: Obviously the "text" of an executable is normally MAP_SHARED, and modifying the instructions after loading would require a private mapping (since you don't want it to change what's on disk).  I think you can do that with `mprotect`, if you implement it the same way Linux (the kernel) does.  Of course the kernel's code isn't backed by a block device, so it can just edit itself in early boot, and it *is* the master copy.

Comment: @o11c - I know about GNU IFUNC, but I don't think it helps here. If I understand it correctly, it necessarily involves an indirect `call` and then a `ret`. It seems like it's just a less portable way of doing the same thing using a mutable global function pointer which originally points to a method that choses the function to run which overwrites the pointer so subsequent invocations directly jump to the selected function. I want "in place" patching of the code, not using `call`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope in-place patching of code will likely perform *worse* since it requires a private mapping.

Comment: @o11c - other than the one time cost to set up the mapping, why would it perform worse during ongoing execution? If anything it could perform better since you could put your private mapping in a hugepage, reducing ITLB pressure.

Comment: One time *per process*. No possibility of sharing, either between simultaneous or subsequent processes. Note that `ld.so` does load from different directories per feature set ... the kernel does what it does because it doesn't *have* an ld.so.

Comment: Yes, there are those costs. Since some of the patched regions will be executed up to billions of times it may still pay off. What do you mean by "Note that ld.so does load from different directories per feature set "? @o11c

Comment: See the `ld.so(1)` man page ... you can completely recompile your code for multiple subarchitectures, at a coarser level than IFUNC. Though I suspect IFUNC with proper optimization is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Intel's `icc` compiler for Linux, you can use the `__notify_intrinsic` feature to allow *additive* patching. That is, it is a method allowing you to safely hook existing functions and add additional behavior - that's somewhat different than `alternative()` which focuses on choosing between two sequences.

`__notify_intrinsic` ensures there is a *probe-ready* instruction sequence at the location in the code you put the intrinsic. This allows you to inject a "probe" (which can really be any arbitrary code) at that point in a safe way, even while the code is executing.

In principle, this could have zero overhead: a *probe-ready* sequence is simply a sequence of 6 instruction bytes<sup>1</sup> that you can safely relocate somewhere else: meaning mostly that the 6 bytes align evenly on instruction boundaries, don't have position dependent code<sup>2</sup>, and don't have any jumps into the range.

The idea is that you can use this probe-ready sequence to modify the behavior at runtime by copying the bytes elsewhere, followed by your new code, and then patch the probe sequence with a `jmp` instruction to your out-of-line "probe" (but the probe can be anything, really).

In practice, `icc` versions 13 through 17 just seem to insert a 6-byte NOP rather than actually trying to use the existing instructions. As an [example](https://godbolt.org/g/6Kgspe), the following C code:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
  if (a < b) {
    __notify_intrinsic("a lt b", 0);
    a *= b;
    return a * b;
  } else {
    __notify_intrinsic("a gt b", 0);
    return a << b;
  }
}
```

Generates this assembly:

```
add:
        cmp       edi, esi                                      #2.11
        jge       ..B1.4        # Prob 50%                      #2.11
        xor       edx, edx                                      #3.5
        .byte     102                                           #
        .byte     15                                            #
        .byte     31                                            #
        .byte     68                                            #
        .byte     0                                             #
        .byte     0                                             #
        imul      edi, esi                                      #4.5
        imul      esi, edi                                      #5.16
        mov       eax, esi                                      #5.16
        ret                                                     #5.16
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.1
        xor       edx, edx                                      #7.5
        .byte     102                                           #
        .byte     15                                            #
        .byte     31                                            #
        .byte     68                                            #
        .byte     0                                             #
        .byte     0                                             #
        mov       ecx, esi                                      #8.17
        shl       edi, cl                                       #8.17
        mov       eax, edi                                      #8.17
        ret
```

The series of 6 `.byte` directives make one six-byte long-`nop` instruction.

The compiler records the location of each `__notify_intrinsic` and other information such as the value of the annotation in a special `.itt_not_tab` section in the ELF binary, which you can examine at runtime.

You can find more details on this approach [in the documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/LowOverheadAnnotations.pdf), but unfortunately it seems limited to Intel's proprietary `icc` compiler at the moment.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's 5 bytes on on 32-bit x86.

<sup>2</sup> For example, a relative jump or `rip`-relative addressing.

Comment: So how does it get these NOPs patched to something useful?  It's not just a `jmp` or `call` is it?

Comment: @PeterCordes As mentioned above, the idea is that you copy the 6 bytes out-of-line somewhere (since they may not be `nops`!), then follow that with whatever code you want to patch in, followed by a `jmp` back to the instruction following the 6 bytes. Then you replace the 6 bytes with a `jmp`: that's why it's 6 bytes, just enough to encode an `FF 25 /32` jump. Of course in the special case the sequence _is_ a `nop` and you could fit some useful code in there you could perhaps just patch it in directly w/o the out-of-line code, but that's not the main use-case.

Comment: You could probably roughly hack up the same thing in `gcc` with a `volatile` inline `asm` block, along with some GAS directives to create a symbol pointing to the nop in some special section. The overhead is only a single `nop` so it's not too back.

Comment: So the final high-performance run-many-times state includes a jump to a block that then jumps back?  Ok, that works for a whole loop or something, but it's more overhead than you'd want for most single instructions (except maybe `pshufb` vs. a no-SSSE3 fallback).  So it's only no-overhead if it turns out you can replace the NOP instead of jumping away?  That's the "in principle" part?

Comment: No, the "high performance" state is the unpatched state where you have 0 or 1 extra `nop` and straight-line code. I.e., you'd organize that to be the case you cared about. The slower case would be the one with the jump (e.g., the user has enabled extra profiling/diagnostics whatever). I see what you are getting at though: the idea that the location will always be patched, which is probably most closely aligned with `alternative()`. I'm interested mostly in two states, with performance more important in the "default" case. @PeterCordes

Comment: If you had several alternatives (i.e., no real "default") and/or you cared about the performance of every scenario fairly equally, you'd probably want a different mechanism which allowed in-place patching, perhaps by messing around with the instruction lengths in the "patch location" and all the alternatives so they are the same length (worst case you can still pad the too-short ones with `nop`s). The Intel thingy however, is more aligned with the "default + the opportunity to add extra code (probes)". In particular, the patching is purely additive: it doesn't let you replace A with B...

Comment: ... but only lets you choose between A and A + B. Of course, you can often organize B to undo the effect of A, so sometimes it's really "alternative" like. You could also "always patch" to get A or B but it kind of sucks as you point out. There are a lot of papers about "hot patching" like this on x86, but a lot of the complexity relating to safe patch sequences disappears if you don't try to do it while other threads are concurrently running the code.  @PeterCordes

Comment: Ok, so this isn't very useful for runtime dispatching of SSE2 vs. AVX2, because you need to not run the SSE2 instructions if you're doing same the work with AVX2 *instead*.  You should probably point out in the answer that it's additive patching only; that's a key limitation.  Still, interesting answer; I didn't know this existed so I'm glad you wrote it up.

Comment: @PeterCordes - correct, but I don't think you'd usually want fine-grained instruction-level dispatching between a single (or a few) SSE or AVX instructions, right? Usually the whole kernel is going to be different and you're just better off compiling the functions in the various interesting permutations and dispatching at a higher level. My (as noted) motivating example (turning on extra instrumentation or debugging) was actually additive, but by comparing it to Linux's `alternative()` macro (which is A vs B) I definitely muddied the waters.

Comment: Right, SSE vs. AVX isn't a good example anyway.  Another Linux `alternative()` use case is SMP vs. UP `lock` prefixes.  That's the kind of thing I think of for `alternative()`.  Anway, yeah I see what you were going for with runtime instrumentation now.  I didn't really re-read the question when I started commenting, I was just thinking about code patching as a way to get zero-overhead runtime dispatching (with no indirection via function pointers).  But yeah you'd just patch the `call` targets for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well unless I was really polishing the turd, I would just dispatch through a function pointer which should be well-predicted except the first time or two, and very close to zero cost compared to actual patching of a static-target `call`. I updated the intro to this answer. Note also that `gcc` offers `ms_hook_prologue`, on a per-function basis, but it's only useful to hook into the _start_ of the function.